# Add in area constraint when assigning probabilities to rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, constraints, assign

I am attempting to generate 1000 simulations of field-level crop assignments that are based on a set of crop probabilities (generated in a separate analysis). What I've done is extracted and aggregated (using the mean) raster pixel-level probabilities to fields, so that each field has a probability associated with each type of crop. Essentially, the dataset I have looks something like this, where the ID corresponds to an individual field.

```
crp_data<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=runif(30,0,0.3),nrow=10,ncol=3))
colnames(crp_data)<-c('Almond','Corn','Soy')
ID<-1:10
mini_dat<-cbind(ID,crp_data)
   ID     Almond       Corn        Soy
1   1 0.06892399 0.06547728 0.13620222
2   2 0.26790834 0.29593780 0.05201943
3   3 0.21228911 0.13332820 0.28494349
4   4 0.19941160 0.17655127 0.18443079
5   5 0.26986918 0.23266005 0.03110367
6   6 0.01985116 0.15348043 0.06481676
7   7 0.24824107 0.16718490 0.04176194
8   8 0.09972657 0.04325504 0.28476090
9   9 0.14981208 0.15580469 0.27743882
10 10 0.28884774 0.16109794 0.04253892
```

I have managed to set up a for loop where I use the crop probabilities to assign crop values to the fields in 1000 simulations, no problem. I first create an empty data-frame and then loop over the rows (by ID) and columns to assign new crops:

```
mat_n<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=nrow(mini_dat),ncol=1000)) 
colnames(mat_n)[1:1000]<-paste0("Sim",1:1000,"")
ID<-unique(mini_dat$ID) #field ID that corresponds with the fields in my mini_dat
mat_n<-cbind(ID,mat_n)

 for (j in 2:ncol(mat_n)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(mat_n)){
    out<-mini_dat[mini_dat$ID %in% mat_n[i,1],] #row of probabilities corresponding to each field
    probs<-as.numeric(out[,2:4])  
    r1<-sample(3, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) #sample from the row, using probabilities 
    mat_n[i,j] <- colnames(out)[r1+1]#gives me the name of the crop in the simulation, i.e, 'Almond'
  }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is add an area constraint so that for each simulation, the probability that each field is assigned a certain crop is altered as the loop runs to account for area of that crop. I.e., for each field in a simulation, as a crop is assigned, the area of the crop assigned so far is updated, and once maxxed out, a different probability is assigned. For each field, the updated probabilities for each crop would be calculated like this:
1-(area of crop X so far/total area of crop X).

What I've done so far is try and use an empty data-frame to update the row-by-row crop areas that pulls from the field-level areas and sums that for each crop for each row, and then when it loops back uses those updated areas in the ratio above. What I have doesn't work, and I think it's because I'm misunderstanding what should go where in terms of the for loop.

```
#dataframe with total crop areas, crop names, and column to hold updated crop totals by row
area_c<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=runif(3,500,10000),nrow=3,ncol=1))
area_c$Crop<-c('Almond','Corn','Soy')
area_c$field_tot<-0
colnames(area_c)[1]<-'C'

#dataframe with individual field crop areas and IDs
area_f<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=runif(3,500,1000),nrow=10,ncol=1))
area_f$ID<-ID
colnames(area_f)[1]<-'fields'

#dataset for updating the areas that matches ncol and nrow of mat_n
area_up<-mini_dat
area_up[,2:4]<-0

for (j in 2:ncol(mat_n)){ #by simulation
    for (i in 1:nrow(mat_n)){ #by ID
      out<-mini_dat[mini_dat$ID %in% mat_n[i,1],] #this pulls out the row of crop probabilities by ID
      var<-out[,2:31] #only probs
      probs<-as.numeric(var) #numeric for sample function
      r1<-sample(30, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) #use IDs of each crop, and then the probs associated with crop
      mat_n[i,j] <-names(var[,r1]) #assign probs originally
      mat_n[i,j]<-ifelse(mat_n[i,j] == area_c$Crop, (1-(area_c$field_tot/area_c$C)), NA)
    }
    for (x in 2:ncol(area_up)){
      area_o<-area_f[area_f$ID %in% out[,1], ] 
      area_o<-area_o[,1]
      area_up[i,x]<-ifelse(out[,1] == area_up$ID & mat_n[i,j] == names(area_up), area_o, 0)
      area_c$field_tot<-colsums(area_up[,2:31])
  }
}
```

Any advice or alternative suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: The first part of your example does not work. That makes it hard to help.

Comment: Hi Robert; I fixed the error (missing a letter in the for loop) so it should run now.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your example does not work, but can be simplified a lot, I think (hard to know as your code does not work)

```
crp <-as.data.frame(matrix(data=runif(30,0,0.3),nrow=10,ncol=3))
colnames(crp) <- c('Almond','Corn','Soy')
```

5 realizations should be enough for the example

```
nsample <- 5
ncrops <- ncol(crp)
set.seed(48)

a <- apply(crp, 1, function(i) sample(ncrops, nsample, prob=i, replace=TRUE))
a <- t(a)
head(a)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    3    3
#[2,]    2    2    1    2    3
#[3,]    3    2    2    2    1
#[4,]    3    1    1    2    1
#[5,]    2    1    2    2    2
#[6,]    3    3    1    3    3
```

Or get their names

```
 a[] <- names(crp)[a]
 head(a)
 #     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]   [,5]    
 #[1,] "Almond" "Almond" "Almond" "Soy"  "Soy"   
 #[2,] "Corn"   "Corn"   "Almond" "Corn" "Soy"   
 #[3,] "Soy"    "Corn"   "Corn"   "Corn" "Almond"
 #[4,] "Soy"    "Almond" "Almond" "Corn" "Almond"
 #[5,] "Corn"   "Almond" "Corn"   "Corn" "Corn"  
 #[6,] "Soy"    "Soy"    "Almond" "Soy"  "Soy"
```

Comment: Thanks Robert; the original first part should work now. This is useful for simplifying, but unfortunately still doesn't address the area constraint for assigning probs.